# Total up columns using sub queries in the SELECT list

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am creating a table that holds total count of rows in three other tables and then work out the totals of all combined.

So far I have :

```sql
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1) T1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) T2,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T3) T3,
       (SELECT (T1+T2+T3)) TOTAL
```

However I get an error message that says T1, T2 and T3 are invalid column names. If I remove the TOTAL subquery then it executes fine.

Any ideas please?

Comment: You cannot use Alias name in select clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cte` :

```
WITH t AS (
     SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1) T1,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) T2,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T3) T3
)

SELECT T1, T2, T3, (T1 + T2 + T3) AS TOTAL
FROM t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use define alias and use in same select. Instead use this script:

```
SELECT T1, T2, T3, T1+T2+T3 AS TOTAL
FROM (  
   SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1) T1,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) T2,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T3) T3
   ) AS tbl
```

Comment: I needed the TOTAL as an adjacent column to the other three values

Comment: So you can also add them to your outer select.